# What is the correct syntax for writing custom attributes in a jQuery method?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a ternary ahead of variable instantiations. The problem is, that this is an incorrect way to assign a variable for an attribute.

```
$partial = $data.cell_info_box === undefined ? job_box : cell_info_box
$rel     = $($data.$partial).attr('rel');
$klass   = $($data.$partial).attr("rel").match(/job/) == null ? 'task' : 'job';
```

How can I provide my ternary like demonstrated but create callable attributes with my initial ternary's product?

Comment: Are you trying to access a property of the `$data` object based on string literals? i.e. are you trying to dig into `$data.job_box`?

Comment: It looks like you want to do `$data[$partial].attr('rel')`, but I can't be sure without knowing what `$data` is.

Comment: It's a JSON object with an attribute `job_box` or `cell_info_box`, so I could access that data normally by doing `$data.job_box` or `$data.cell_info_box`

Comment: Ah wow you solved it! please let me give you credit! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment, what you want is `$data[$partial]`. This syntax is used when you want to get a value from an object without knowing the key name until runtime. You may also see this problem incorrectly solved through the use of eval but this is the correct way.